# Velostrata: Boot fails while migrating Azure VM to GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to migrate Azure VM to GCP via Velostrata and facing below issues:

============================ port: 1 ============================

SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-20191010_205345-google)

Total RAM Size = 0x00000000f0000000 = 3840 MiB

CPUs found: 1

Max CPUs supported: 1

Comparing RSDP and RSDP

Comparing RSDT and RSDT

Comparing FACP and FACP

Comparing FACS and FACS

return 0 for FACS vs FACS: SUCCESS

Comparing DSDT and DSDT

return 0 for DSDT vs DSDT: SUCCESS

return 0 for FACP vs FACP: SUCCESS

Comparing SRAT and SRAT

return 0 for SRAT vs SRAT: SUCCESS

Comparing APIC and APIC

return 0 for APIC vs APIC: SUCCESS

Comparing SSDT and SSDT

return 0 for SSDT vs SSDT: SUCCESS

Comparing WAET and WAET

return 0 for WAET vs WAET: SUCCESS

return 0 for RSDT vs RSDT: SUCCESS

return 0 for RSDP vs RSDP: SUCCESS

found virtio-scsi at 0:3

virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0

virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520 = 10240 MiB

drive 0x000f2830: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520

Sending Seabios boot VM event.

Booting from Hard Disk 0...

VELOS initialising devices...ok

Velostrata Boot Loader

VELOS 1.0.0+ (0319) -- Velostrata -- http://velostrata.com/

Features: DNS HTTP iSCSI TFTP SRP VLAN AoE ELF MBOOT PXE bzImage Menu PXEXT

Google Compute Engine - boot via metadata

CPU: GenuineIntel

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.30GHz

net0: 42:01:0a:90:00:0a using virtio-net on 0000:00:04.0 (closed)

[Link:up, TX:0 TXE:0 RX:0 RXE:0]

Configuring (net0 42:01:0a:90:00:0a)..... ok

net0: 10.144.0.10/255.255.255.255 gw 10.144.0.1

http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/ipxeboot.
.. ok

net0: 10.144.0.10/255.255.255.255 gw 10.144.0.1

Initiator IQN iqn.2014-05.com.velostrata.int.s7l1n4ph:vlst-7

Target root path iscsi:10.144.0.4::::iqn.2014-05.com.velostrata.iscsi.base:vlst-7

Target replica path iscsi:10.144.0.5::::iqn.2014-05.com.velostrata.iscsi.base:vlst-7

Hook attempt 1 at 2019-11-15 14:23:49

Boot attempt 1 at 2019-11-15 14:23:49

Could not open SAN device: Input/output error (http://ipxe.org/1d704039)

Boot attempt 2 at 2019-11-15 14:28:35

Could not open SAN device: Input/output error (http://ipxe.org/1d704039)

Boot attempt 3 at 2019-11-15 14:33:20

============================ port: 2 ============================

============================ port: 3 ============================

============================ port: 4 ============================

This question is similar to
[GCP boot error - Could not open SAN device Input/output error](https://serverfault.com/questions/973374/gcp-boot-error-could-not-open-san-device-input-output-error)

Job Message:
[Cloud instance boot failed] (Instance boot was unsuccessful)

Velostrata moves the VM back and hence it gets deleted from GCP environment.

**Snapshot: Velostrata Moves the VM Back**

[image: Snapshot: Velostrata Moves the VM Back]

**Snapshot: Job failure description**

[image: Snapshot: Job failure description]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of known issues in Velostrata 4.0 and 4.2 that could return that error

**Issue**

Cloud instance boot failed (Instance boot was unsuccessful)

**Diagnostic Steps**

1. Collect [Support Bundle](https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/support/saving-a-support-bundle)
2. Open management-service.log
3. Grep for the following log line:

   2019-04-30 15:49:52.712 [tasks-8] INFO  VSphereServiceGrpcClient - {parentTaskId=t-8, step=stateRollbackRunInCloudTask, task=RunVmInCloud, taskId=t-9} Marking task as failed, taskId: task-25315, reason: Cloud instance boot failed

2019-04-30 {"step":"stateMonitorInstanceSuccessfulBoot","task":"RunVmInCloud","taskId":"t-32"},"threadId":246,"threadPriority":5}

**Resolution**

1. Depending on the OS, install [prep package](https://cloud.google.com/velostrata/docs/how-to/prepare-vms-servers/preparing-linux-vms) correctly with its
   dependencies
2. Open Port 3260 (TCP)for iSCSI communication. Cloud Edges connect to
   Migrated VM using port 3260 (iSCSI). This port must be open between
   VM subnet and both Cloud Edges.
3. If source VM is on-premise, backend must be able to resolve FQDN of
   the local ESXi host that the VM is registered with. This is because
   the Backend mounts the VMDK disk files directly. Velostrata Backend
   connects to ESXi host on port 902 (TCP) during disk copy, check that
   this port is open.
4. Open firewall for port 9111 and 443 (TCP)for inbound on the subnet
   which hosts the Velostrata FEs. On-premise backed connects to Cloud
   Edges on port 9111 (TLS). On-premise backed connects to Velostrata
   Manager on port 443 (HTTPS) and 9119 (TCP).

**Root Cause**

Might be various: iSCSI service not reachable, prep package not installed properly, firewall issue.